# Wiring events to a UITextView

Tags: objective-c, iphone, events, uitextview

I can't seem to wire events to my UITextView.

I'm *expecting* that the list of events that are available for the UITextField ("Did End On Exit", "Editing Changed", etc) , should all be available for the UITextView.

However this isn't the case.  UITextView in its events listing shows *nothing*.

What's going on here and how do I trap events for UITextView?

Comment: I wrote a class which implements the UITextViewDelegate protocol, but I cannot find how to connect the "delegate" outlet to the class I wrote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your Files Owner implements the UITextFieldDelegate connect the delegate output of your UITextView to the Files Owner. Simple

Comment: im getting a bit confused on this

Answer (score 6):

Your view controller will need to implement the UITextViewDelegate.

```
@interface SaveGameViewController : UIViewController<UITextViewDelegate>
```

After you add the UITextViewDelegate to your view controller, open Interface Builder, and you can find this "delegate" hook under the First Owner.

In my case, I have a text view within a SaveGameView that is the view of SaveGameViewController and, when open my SaveGameViewController.xib in IB, I can wire the text view to delegate within First Owner so that the view controller will respond to the delegate event:

```
-(IBAction)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView;
```

This method is also within SaveGameViewController

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting a delegate which implements the [UITextViewDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html)?

Comment: No, I am not.  I see there is a different outlet here in the UITextView called "delegate", but its not clear what I do with that outlet.  How do I hook that outlet up to my class which implements the UITextViewDelegate protocol?  An example would be nice.

Comment: See iPhone SDK sample 'UICatalog', files TextViewController.h and TextViewController.m.

http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/samplecode/UICatalog/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007710